# No Such File or Directory Error In Linux

Tags: linux, sublimetext2

I'm trying to update Sublime Text 2 editor from 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 in my Linux Mint Virtual Machine.  I removed old directory and untarred the new file into a directory.  It appears to be ok, but when I run './sublime_text' I get a 'No such file or directory' error even though the file appears to be there.  It has executable permissions, and I'm running it with sudo logged in as root.  I can't figure out why it doesn't recognize the executable.

```
 mint10-dev64 etc # ./sublime_text
```

I was thinking this was an error because I was installing 32 bit. When I install 64 bit I get this error:

```
mint10-dev64 Sublime Text 2 # pwd
/home/devuser/Documents/Sublime Text 2
mint10-dev64 Sublime Text 2 # ls -la
total 8516
drwxr-xr-x 5 devuser devuser    4096 2013-07-07 20:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 devuser devuser    4096 2013-07-15 11:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 devuser devuser    4096 2013-07-07 20:21 Icon
drwxr-xr-x 2 devuser devuser    4096 2013-07-07 20:21 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 devuser devuser    4206 2013-07-07 20:21 PackageSetup.py 
drwxr-xr-x 2 devuser devuser    4096 2013-07-07 20:21 Pristine Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 devuser devuser   10838 2013-07-07 20:21 sublime_plugin.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 devuser devuser 8662712 2013-07-07 20:21 sublime_text
mint10-dev64 Sublime Text 2 # ./sublime_text
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying
GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Terminated
```

Comment: are you in the right directory? show us `pwd` and `ls -la`.

Comment: is there actually a file named `sublime_text` in etc?  Just asking because etc is a pretty odd place for executables, and `./` means execute a file in the current directory

Comment: Presumably the problem *only* happens when using `sudo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're trying to run it as `root`. Run as user `devuser`  (from within the `/home/devuser/Documents/Sublime Text 2` directory) and it should be OK. I think your original error came from the fact that you were trying to run `./sublime_text` from within the `/etc` directory, and it wasn't installed there. The `./` part of your command means "run the file named thus-and-such **in the current directory**".